# How to plot selected rows that are datetime in x axis and another column in y axis

Tags: python, datetime, plot

I have currency exchange data of 3 days that are in 15 min interval. I changed the date column into datetime and when plotting in matplotlib it gives x axis scales of 12 hours. How can I select say 3 hours of data and plot with given 15 minutes time interval?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(EURJPY['Date'],EURJPY['Close'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I also tried this code but it gives output that have x axis values as row numbers.

```
EURJPY.loc[(EURJPY['Date'] > '07/05/2021 07:00') & (EURJPY['Date'] <= '07/05/2021 11:00')].plot(y='Close')
```

How can I select ,say close values of 9a.m to 1 p.m?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just slice your `x` and `y` values in the first snippet based on the logic in the last

```py
idx = (EURJPY['Date'] > '07/05/2021 07:00') & (EURJPY['Date'] <= '07/05/2021 11:00')
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(EURJPY.loc[idx,'Date'],EURJPY.loc[idx,'Close'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked. It shows 30 minutes time interval in x axis. Thank you